# How to swipe out of table view controller (not the cells) - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a tab bar app. It has 5 tabs. I have the 3rd tab connected to a navigation controller that's connected to a table view controller. Simple enough, right?

Well, I recently decided to implement left/right swipe gestures as an optional way to navigate left and right to each tab in the tab bar controlled app. The gestures work great, except I don't have a way to implement the gestures on the 3rd tab (the one with the `UITableView`) because there's no implementation file associated with it.

And that's my question: How can I implement the gestures on the third tab so I can navigate AWAY from it by swiping?? I can swipe *into* that tab, but not *out* of it. I'm fairly new to iOS dev, and I really appreciate any help!

(Using ARC, Storyboard, & Xcode 4.5.2)

**EDIT:**
Here's a screenshot of how my Table View Controller is connected to my Tab Bar Controller:
[image]

**SOLUTION:**
The answer marked correct is indeed correct. It explained to me how to make a subclass of my UITableViewController.  But I was also wondering how to implement my TableView programmatically... so after a bit of searching, this link pretty much shows exactly how to do that: [Ruchi Raval's post on mobisoftinfotech](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/). However, I ended up just following the steps in the link, and I ended up deleting my original UITableViewController because I had created a new one through the steps in the link and connected it to my NavigationController through the Storyboard (ctrl + drag).

Hope this helps anyone that had my same quesions!

Comment: No implementation file because it's just a UITableViewController?  Make a subclass of UITableViewController and implement the gestures there, too.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how/where to make a subclass, but I'll try and figure it out and see if it works.

Comment: I'm having a tough time figuring out how to subclass it...

Comment: It's hard to explain without pictures and a super-precise understanding of what you have in the project so far, but I took a crack at it below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control gestures on a VC, you'll need your own subclass.  Create a new objective-c object named like MyTableViewController.  Xcode lets you specify a superclass when creating the files, use UITableViewController.

Xcode provides some template code in the new files -- leave that alone to begin with.  In storyboard, I think the tab you're trying to fix has a navigation (vc) whose root vc is a UITableViewController.

Select that table vc and select the Identity inspector (upper right, third tab from the left).  You should see a section called custom class.  The current class is probably UITableViewController.  Change that to MyTableViewController, or whatever you named the new class.

Build and run.  Now you control that table vc.  Back in it's implementation file, you can add your gesture code in viewDidLoad:.

Comment: You're pretty much right on about the layout. So I followed what you instructed, and the swiping works through all the tabs, but the newly created subclass just covers up the UITableView completely (so it's just a blank view in between the tabs and title bar). Do I need to figure out how to implement all of the table view UI into the subclass in order to make it visible and useable?

Comment: If I'm understanding you, yes.  You would supply the data and presentation logic to fill a table, and everything on all of the other view controllers for that matter

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to do that. But FYI I've added a screenshot to my original question...not sure if it will help, but it's there.

Comment: It looks like I expected.  I'm not sure if your question is a simple one (like a beginner question) or a deeper one.  I'll answer the simple one and ask your forgiveness in advance if I am treating it too simply:  Yes - it's the whole job of an iOS developer to write code, much of it in UIViewController subclasses, to control what your app looks like and does.  The UITableViewController is an example of this work.  Your main job there is to implement the delegate and datasource methods for the table view.

Comment: Also, how to implement the table is an entirely different set of questions than the one asked and answered here.  Would you be so kind as to mark this question correct as you see fit, then search/ask SO/ask me about how to implement table VCs?  Cheers.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll mark this answer as the correct answer because I'm sure this is the correct solution, even though I still do not no how apply it.